# is there away to ping heroku app from windows iam getting request time out

Tags: heroku, dart, flutter

getting request timeout on my heroku app , not able to ping the host from windows ,  but iam able to invoke my rest api from postMan

SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'plantspricemainapp.herokuapp.com'

iam trying to get data from 
https://plantspricemainapp.herokuapp.com/retrieve_plants_price/date
if iam using postman its working fine, in flutter iam getting 
SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'plantspricemainapp.herokuapp.com'

also not able to ping plantspricemainapp.herokuapp.com or www.plantspricemainapp.herokuapp.com  getting request timeout

E/flutter (15318): SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'plantspricemainapp.herokuapp.com' (OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7)
E/flutter (15318): #0      IOClient.send (package:http/src/io_client.dart:33:23)

var response = await http.get("https://plantspricemainapp.herokuapp.com/retrieve_plants_price/date");

expected i should get response same as my postman call

actual: 
E/flutter (15318): SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'plantspricemainapp.herokuapp.com' (OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7)
E/flutter (15318): #0      IOClient.send (package:http/src/io_client.dart:33:23)

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I have the same problem using the Android emulator.

Comment: I have no similar problems with iOS simulator. I connected with no problem to my herokuapp.

So, I believe that the android simulator has to be configured.

Comment: yes heroku require bearer token to be send in the header if you using rest call.